# Select 1 Updates Select 2, but Select 2 doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I'm trying to have Select 1 update Select 2 and then have Select 2 fire.

Select 2 only fires when controlled directly..  I'm stumped!!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Select Firing</title> 
</head>
<body>
<p>Select 1 updates Select 2, but select 2's alert does not fire</p>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<p>Select 2 only fires alert when controlled directly</p>
<div>
<select id="select2" onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() { //run on document.ready
  $("#select1").change(function() { //this occurs when select 1 changes
    $("#select2").val($(this).val());
  });
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#select1").change(function() {

    $("#select2").val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
    //or
    $("#select2").val($(this).val()).change();

});
```

Is this what you need? Or did i miss something?